# How do I include C++ header and libraries in C#?

Tags: c#, image-processing

How do I use C++ header and libraries in C#?. I am currently working on my project and I would like to use Pixel Based Adaptive Segmenter (PBAS) that is only available in C++. Is there a way?

Comment: I believe you can use an interop assembly, but I don't think you can just use standard C++ libraries within C# as they are compiled differently.  Not 100% sure on that though, but just hoping to point you in the right direction.

Comment: Take a look at C++/CLI http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379617%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: ...If i'm going to use C++, I don't have much idea to do this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19814661/how-do-i-include-existing-remote-libraries-and-header-in-c

Answer (score 1):

Depends a lot on what you are trying to call and how complex it is.  For simple things you can use a DllImport attribute.  For example:

```
[DllImport("User32.dll")] static extern Boolean MessageBeep(UInt32 beepType);
```

Will import MessageBeep from User32.dll.  When doing this you have to be very aware that you are calling into unmanaged code from managed code and that pointers may be handled differently.

If you have a tlb (type library) or self registering dll you can generally select it as a reference in Visual Studio and binding (known as Interop) will be created for you.

As was mentioned in the comments you can also use C++/CLI to write a wrapper class that will bridge the managed and unmanaged worlds.

If it were me I'd first see if VS will just accept this as a reference (try the tlb first if it is available).

Comment: ...I'm still confuse what pl to use (C++ or C#). I'm much familiar with C#, if I will use C++ directly this is what I must know http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19814661/how-do-i-include-existing-remote-libraries-and-header-in-c.

Comment: I assumed from you question you wished to use C# and targeted my answer accordingly.  If you are using Visual Studio, go into (or create) your C# project.  Add a reference to the dll (or better tlb) you wish to use and see if it fails/complains.  If the add reference succeeds use the object browser to look at the available methods.  If you can't get VS to generate an interop for you, try adding a DllImport to your C# that uses the dll you want and the method you are interested in.